when chebyshev's equality holds?
Chebyshev's inequality states that for any random variable $X$ with finite expected value $E(X)$ and variance $\text{Var}(X)$,the probability that
$X$ deviates from its mean by at least $a$ is bounded by:
$$P(|X-E(X)|\geq a)\leq \dfrac{\text{Var}(X)}{a^2}.$$
But I have a question that when the equality holds? Can we find all random variables $X$ that satisfy $$P(|X-E(X)|\geq a)=\dfrac{\text{Var}(X)}{a^2},a>0.$$
Any help would be appreciated

The equality holds for any constant random variable. If I am not mistaken, that is the only class of Random variables for which it will hold.

@sudeep5221 can you explain why or give a proof for it?

Hint: what if $a = \operatorname{Var}(X) / 2$?

@mihaild $a$ is a given positive real number. We can't choose $a$

Do you want for given $a$ find $X$ s.t. your equality is satisfied, or do you want an $X$ s.t. your equality is satisfied for all $a$?

@AlexNguyen Chebyshev inequality is a corollary of Markov's inequality and in Markov's inequality, the equality holds only when $X$ is a constant. You can refer to this for a proof.
